# Sorted ObservableCollection with KeyValuePair and duplicated keys

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, observablecollection

I have a `foreach` loop. Each loop I get a value (long) and name (string) of an item.

Now I want to create an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Int32, String>>()` but not with the value, but with a new index starting with 0. The collection should be sorted by the value. If there is a duplicate value, both items should be added.

**Example:**

```
var tempList= new SortedList<long, String>();

foreach (INetworkItem item in ListOfItems)
{
    long value = item.ticks;
    string name = item.name;

    // tried:
    // tempList.Add(value , name );
    ...
}
```

Content `ListOfItems`:

- 3444423423, "aaaaaa"
- 9999457567, "bbbbbb"
- 1111100065, "cccccc"
- 3444423423, "aaaaaa"

After the foreach-loop I need an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Int32, String>>()` which looks like:

- 0, "cccccc"
- 1, "aaaaaa"
- 2, "aaaaaa"
- 3, "bbbbbb"

How can I do that?

Comment: define sort please. how you compare values? ordinal string comparison?

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @dotctor Sorted means that the string with the lowest number should be the first in the collection

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've tried: see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to sort the `ListOfItems` by ticks.

```
var items = ListOfItems.OrderBy(x => x.ticks);
```

Then you should convert them to the format you want

> 0, "cccccc"
>   1, "aaaaaa"
>   2, "aaaaaa"
>   3, "bbbbbb"

You can do this by [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
items = items.Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int,string>(i, x.name));
```

Then initialize your collection with it.

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<Int32, String>>(items);
```